# How to check the case of any variable in jinja2/django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I need to check the variable's case like if it is in upper case or lower case. Can we do that in Django template ?

Comment: You can write your own filter or template tag to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `upper` test provided by Jinja.

```
{% if variable is upper %}Yes, the variable is uppercase!{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that variable will be a string, you can use `isupper` method of string to check if string is in uppercase or not. Similarly, `islower` for checking lowercase.

@agaust. Thanks for edit, the builtin functions skipped my mind.

Comment: isupper() I can use only in Python Script not in Tag. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can, for eg. in template {% if variable.isupper %} Then show it {% endif %}